# Compiler error when calling dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to add a button on Annotation,
but I'm getting an error on line:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

which shows that:

> no known class method for the selector dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier.

I really don't know how to fix it And I appreciate any help.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapAnnotation class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    // Create a UIButton object to add on the 

    UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
    [leftButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [annotationView setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:leftButton];

    return annotationView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

with this:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

Take care of the Capital letters:

MapView is not the same of mapView.

Comment: Thankssss!! I don't know how I miss it